# Recover information from android recorded 3gpp audio file

Tags: data-recovery

So i made 5 audio records, all of them seems to have infotmation because they have size betwen 100Mb-150Mb, the problem is that some metadata was deleded, like lenght, bit rate, audio sample rate, etc from all the files.

Because of this i cant open the files, i want to be able to recover the file, i tried to use audacity or sounforge but it just play static.

I read that editing the hex i can modify the meta missing but it didnt explain much more. Any help is welcome

Comment: Do these files play on the original device that they were recorded on? It is possible that it uses fixed values for recording - what was it and what version of which software was used to make the recording? Please expand your question to include this information.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Please also note this site is about recommending *software,* not [howtos](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/882/185). If you're after the latter, [SU] might be a better place to ask. If you're looking for software, please [edit] your question and add missing details like the OS it should run on and how much money you're willing to spend. For details, see [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185)